# Difference between obfuscate and obscure?

Tags: differences

I see the words used in the same situations. Is there a particular difference that would help me understand when each one should be used?

Etymology Obfuscate
Latin `fuscus` for *dark*

Etymology Obscure
Latin `obscurus` for *dark*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If you are being ***evasive, unclear***, or obscure about a **truth**, you are
>   **[obfuscating](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obfuscate)**.

*I would use obfuscation when truth is played with deliberately.*

- The people who are good at *obfuscating* would include defense lawyers and politicians.
- The loan contract was filled with legal words meant to *obfuscate* trusting borrowers.

> If something is **[obscure](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obscure)**, it's ***vague and hard to see.***

- Be careful if you're driving in heavy rain — the painted lines can be *obscured*.
- The big elm tree *obscures* our view of the valley.
- The information was *obscured* by price stickers
- It was a way to *obscure* the sun or the moon.

Comment: I believe the poster wanted to know the difference between the verb forms. Your definition of "obscure" is adjectival, even though not all of your examples are.

Comment: In the first of your examples of *obscure*, you are not using it as a verb. If you want it to be a verb it would have to be *obscured*, as the past participle would be required. The way you have it is as an adjective or complement to the verb 'to be'.

Comment: @WS2, post updated, thanks,the distinction was obscured.

Comment: I actually wasn't looking specifically for the verb forms, or any other specific form of the words. These words seem to have other forms that are used more or less often than the other. The examples here are excellent for understanding the key difference in definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Both words can be used as verbs in a sense meaning "to hide" something. You can obscure my view of the painting by standing in front of me or draping the artwork with a cloth, but that's not obfuscation. When you obfuscate, you also befuddle or confuse, though this can be *unintentional*. For example, if you use a lot of jargon you might unknowingly obfuscate the true meaning of your words (i.e., render yourself unintelligible) to a layperson or, through fast talk and slick rhetoric, you may purposefully hide your meaning.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using them both as verbs, i.e. someone is trying to be vague about what they are stating, "obscure" is probably a bit softer (like, maybe they're trying to spare someone's feelings) - "obfuscate" is more like intentional deception.